# AWS comparison between nodegroup and managed nodegroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, eksctl

I use eksctl to create EKS cluster on AWS

After create a yaml configuration file define EKS cluster follow [docs](https://eksctl.io/usage/creating-and-managing-clusters/), when I run the command `eksctl create cluster -f k8s-dev/k8s-dev.yaml` to execute the create cluster action, the log show some lines below:

```
2021-12-15 16:23:55 [ℹ]  will create a CloudFormation stack for cluster itself and 1 nodegroup stack(s)
2021-12-15 16:23:55 [ℹ]  will create a CloudFormation stack for cluster itself and 0 managed nodegroup stack(s)
```

What is the different between `nodegroup` and `managed nodegroup`?

I have read from official [docs from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managed-node-groups.html) about `managed nodegroup` but I'm still can not clearly which exactly reason to choose `nodegroup` or `managed nodegroup`?

What would you use when you need to create a EKS cluster?

Answer (score 2):

`eksctl` only provide option for you to choose `nodeGroups` or `managedNodeGroups`  docs: https://eksctl.io/usage/container-runtime/#managed-nodes but not describe the different. But I think the follow document will give you the information you need

It describe the different features between `EKS managed node groups` - `Self managed nodes` and `AWS Fargate`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/eks-compute.html

Depend on which purpose you want to use to choose the match one with your purpose, and if I was you, I will choose `managed nodegroup`.